# Vertex dots disappear after using knife project but edges remain

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges

Let me start by saying im still learning and have been designing very simple stuff learning as I go. This has been giving me some trouble but I've always just kind of worked around it. There was a similar question to mine in the search but i wasnt able to have an answer for it.

[1]: [image]
Selecting both the item using to cut and the item to be cut

[2]: [image]
Before cutting the object, the verticies are clearly visible and selectable

[3]: [image]
Selecting the knife project tool

[4]: [image]
Object has been cut and I checked cut through to cut both sides

[5]: [image]
As you can see, vertices are clearly gone, but edges remain intact and are now the only way I can edit the object.

This is my first post so please forgive any formatting errors.

Comment: In edit mode, use ctrl+tab, so that you can choose/come back to vertex edition (or faces, or edges)

Comment: I didnt even know this existed, thank you so much.

Comment: FYI this corresponds to the 3 buttons which are on the right of the manipulators on the bottom bar.